# Laravel 5.3:Full access to all methods in a controller after authentication

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

Friends, I want to know how to implement a full access to a controller's
all methods after authentication.

**Background**: I am using Laravel 5.3, very new to it. I have used native
`auth` and successfully implemented as a middleware that, after authentication,
shows the home page, ex. for admin or a given role, with several menu items specific to that role.

When the role clicks a menu item, it accesses a role specific controller. All
the menu items of a role are methods in the role specific controller.

The interface is designed in such a way that when the role wants to see details 
of an entry it is fetched through ajax request, implemented through role-linked-ajax-controller (through role-specific-interface/role-specific-repository).

Every role has a ajax `controller/interface/repository`.

The role-specific-controller essentially accesses the repository to go through all sorts of logic(db calls, calculations etc.) and returns the result to role- specific-controller which generates the final view.

I have done for 6 different roles but facing a problem.

What i want to know. How to write the routes that give access to all methods in a controller after authentication. Right now I am writing the 'uses' => 'controllers@methods'. I am afraid, I have to define more than 500 such routes for the whole package. Honestly, I am not 100% clear on the routes and access definitions.

Is there a way, after authentication, gives access to role specific controller (all methods in it), its role specific ajax controller (all methods in it) and its linked interface and repository.

Comment: Instead try using Route::resource()

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Route::resource()` for `CRUD` methods of controller. For any other methods you'll have to define a `route` and corresponding `method` in controller.

You can give access to all controller method by using `middleware` in the constructor of Controller like below.

```
    /**
 * ..
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have exactly the same code in my middleware for each role. i am still not able to define the Route::resource() as i am not able to define it correctly. What is the definition of resource.

Comment: can you post your `web.php` file for routes ?